# Использование нескольких глобальных переменных в одной ссылке

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый вечер, коллеги! Сейчас столкнулся с проблемной, когда в одной ссылке используется несколько супер-глобальных массивов $_GET. Имеется вот такая выдержка из кода. Используя ?view=... определяется какая страница должна загрузиться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а при нажатии на эти ссылки должен измениться сам контент страницы. Подскажите, как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просьба в следующий раз не скрин с экрана, а нормальный код прикреплять.
Вы неправильно формируете ссылки, нужно так:

```
<div class="enterprises">
    <a href="http:://localhost/websites/AsiaBest/pageControl.php?view=profile&show=enterprises">Предприятия</a>
    <a href="http:://localhost/websites/AsiaBest/pageControl.php?view=profile&show=products">Продукты</a>
</div>
```

Акцентирую.
pageControl.php?view=profile **/?** show=enterprises *(неправильно)*
pageControl.php?view=profile **&** show=enterprises *(правильно)*

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все сработало!

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятен вопрос. Если подразумевается, что должен при нажатии на ссылку меняться контент без перезагрузки страницы, то надо использовать ajax.
[Пример ajax с использованием jQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/42426/)